# Whats the best way to refresh a token that expires every 2 minutes in react expo?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, oauth, expo

I am now using a setTimeout to refresh the token each time, but it doesnt seem ideal to me and i am wondering if there is a better way. Currently my refreshToken function is below:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const g = setTimeout(() => {
      accessToken ? clearTimeout(g) : refreshCurrentToken(g);
    }, 120000);
  }, [token]);
```

and this is how i refresh the next access token that i receive

```
async function refreshCurrentToken(g) {
    axios
      .post("https://login.iee.ihu.gr/token", {
        grant_type: "refresh_token",
        code: refresh,
        client_id: cID,
        client_secret: cSecret,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        //set the new token
        setToken(res.data.access_token);
        //set the new refresh token
        setRefresh(res.data.refresh_token);
        clearTimeout(g);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The authorization server controls experation not the developer

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what is the exact use case but general practice is to make the required api call first and if you get http code 401 then you use the refresh token to get the new token.